# HTML word-wrap with div tag width set as a percentage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put text under a button in HTML/CSS. I want the text underneath the button to be centered vertically together.

I've achieved this but now the text increases the width of the button. I've been trying to do a word-wrap but it seems like its not possible when you use percentages to define your div tag's width.

Is there a way I can center the text with the button and word-wrap it when using percentages for the width?

Thanks

---

#### EDIT :

Button definition:

```
a.button {
     background-clip: padding-box;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     white-space: nowrap;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
}
a.button span {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

The two sections:

```
div.blockA {
    width: 35%;
}
div.blockB {
    width: 65%;
}
```

The image for the button (in a previous post, I tried to layout four buttons in the center):

```
div.image {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: is using percentages mandatory?

Comment: I used percentages because I am developing it so it can fit most phone screens. But I am also really unexperienced with html (less than a months worth) so I don't know if this is the best way of approaching things. I am open to suggestions

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVLxoM check out my example this if its of any help